# Incidence angle in Sailplane

Tags: wing, glider, angle-of-attack, sailplane

I am determining the shape of the fuselage of a sailplane and I found something that gives me a little conflict, and that is that in most sailplanes it has an inclined tip, I read that this helps reduce drag, but I also see that the wing is not at some notable angle of incidence for the best L/D, with this in mind three questions arose:

1. Do sailplane wings adjust just right for best L/D? because I also had the doubt that adjusting it at this point causes any inclination to drop this relationship and I don't know if it would be optimal to use degrees before the best L/D.
2. Does the tilt of the nose affect this angle or is it only designed for drag? I also read about visibility.
3. Is figure a and b equivalent? not in terms of drag, but in a possible configuration without considering pilot visibility.

[image: Wing incidence Angle. a) Fuselage Inclined b) wing inclined]

Comment: Where did you read that it reduces drag?

Comment: Does "inclined tip" mean washout?

Comment: What do you mean by "the wings adjust?"  What does the adjusting - the designer, the ailerons, the aeroelasticity?